# Cannot update within Eloquent chunk without disrupting chunking

Tags: postgresql, laravel, eloquent

I need to iterate thru a certain number of rows and update them based on results of an API call:

```
Item::whereIn('id', $ids)->chunk(5, function ($items) {
    $skus = $chunk->pluck('sku')->toArray();
    $pricing = $this->api->getPrices($skus); // Requires chunks of 5 SKUs.

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if (!empty($pricing[$item->sku])) {
            $item->price = $pricing[$item->sku];
            $item->save();
        }
    }
});
```

However, if the `save()` call actually changes a row in the database, then the next chunk of items includes some of the items changed in the previous chunk.

This causes some items in the original query result to be missed. I can see this by monitoring the contents of `$skus` using Xdebug which shows subsequent chunks getting SKUs that were already updated (the contents of `$ids` are unique).

For instance, if there were 30 items returned, you'd get 6 chunks of 5. If 5 items have changes that cause the database to update those rows, then only 25 items might actually be processed by the loop.

If I remove `$item->save()` from within the callback, then it finishes processing the rest of the chunks with no SKUs rotated to the next chunk. However, not being able to save completely defeats the purpose.

If I change the code to do this then I still have the same issue:

```
Item::whereId($item->id)->update($item->getAttributes());
```

This is under Laravel 5.3 with PostgreSQL 9.6.

From what I can tell, this does not happen with MySQL, so it appears to be a Postgres quirk.

I can get around this problem by adding the class var `$updates` of type `Collection` and change `$items->save();` to this:

```
if ($item->isDirty()) {
    $this->updates->push($item);
}
```

Then after all the chunks are done, process the updates like this **outside** of the chunking loop:

```
if ($this->updates->count()) {
    foreach ($this->updates as $update) {
        $update->save();
    }
}
```

If I have a particularly large result set that has to be processed, then I could run up against memory problems storing a really large Collection until it reaches the end.

Why can't I update records within the chunk without breaking it and how do I (or can I) fix that?

Sample contents of `$item` as requested:

```
App\Models\Items (22) (
    protected table -> string (5) "items"
    protected guarded -> array (1) [
        string (2) "id"
    ]
    protected connection -> NULL
    protected primaryKey -> string (2) "id"
    protected keyType -> string (3) "int"
    protected perPage -> integer 15
    public incrementing -> bool TRUE
    public timestamps -> bool TRUE
    protected attributes -> array (6) [
        'id' => integer 2
        'sku' => string (9) "GM-705-24"
        'price' => integer 3788
        'quantity' => integer 10
        'created_at' => string (19) "2016-10-11 01:50:45"
        'updated_at' => string (19) "2016-10-11 01:50:45"
    ]
    protected original -> array (6) [
        'id' => integer 2
        'sku' => string (9) "GM-705-24"
        'price' => integer 3788
        'quantity' => integer 10
        'created_at' => string (19) "2016-10-11 01:50:45"
        'updated_at' => string (19) "2016-10-11 01:50:45"
    ]
    protected relations -> array (0)
    protected hidden -> array (0)
    protected visible -> array (0)
    protected appends -> array (0)
    protected fillable -> array (0)
    protected dateFormat -> NULL
    protected casts -> array (0)
    protected touches -> array (0)
    protected observables -> array (0)
    protected with -> array (0)
    public exists -> bool TRUE
    public wasRecentlyCreated -> bool FALSE
)
```

Example of the contents of `$pricing`:

```
array (3) [
    'GM-705-24' => float 37.88,
    'GM-805-25' => float 25.01,
    'GM-715-26' => float 15.05,
]
```

Comment: can you include the output of array $pricing and $items

Comment: @NewbeeDev I've included samples of each. Note that this is a sample for `$item` not `$items`. The variable `$items` is just a standard Eloquent collection as passed to the callback per normal.

Comment: can you put print_r($pricing[$item->sku]); inside your array see if the datas being save are correct

Comment: Yes, I already know the data is correct. That isn't the issue. For instance, I can manually do the update on 5 items outside of the chunk and it works fine. The contents of `$items` will be the same thing as what you see but it will be wrapped in an Eloquent Collection. The same type returned by Eloquent when it creates chunks as shown in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#chunking-results

Comment: How are you getting the `$ids`?

Comment: @RossWilson it's just a simple array of integers passed to the job this exists in. Ex: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`